# Can we open a file in google drive in read mode using python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to read a file in read mode which is in google drive. Can we use Drive-API to open it in read mode instead of downloading it?

My folder structure

```
user
    >1 
      >1.json
```

In this example, I have reached till my json file and now instead of downloading I need to read the file contents in .json.
Normally, we use `with open('1.json') as f:` in python but how can I read and store contents using DRIVE API

Comment: Could you actually explain what you mean by open in read mode? Do you want only to get the metadata? In python with the [get()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get) method you are not downloading the file just reading the metadata.

Comment: How do I use the get() function? I tried result = service.files().get(file_id).execute(). this didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is impossible, you cannot read the information of the file without downloading the actual file. If you think about it you will see that it makes no sense to be able to ready the bytes without actually getting to your computer.

If what you mean is not to create an actual file, you could try to use the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module and store it in memory.

Actually there are examples in the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive):

```
file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

In this case we create the `request` with the [`get_media()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get_media) method without executing it, after that we introduce the request to the [`MediaIoBaseDownload`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseDownload-class.html), this class is responsible to download the data in chunks (in case the file is big) to a [io.Base](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) object `fh`in this code snippet.

---

Now that I think about it, in this case when the file is small enough you could probably just execute the get_media request without the need of chunking the download.

So probably in your case just execute the following code

```
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    file_id = "<your file ID> "
    response = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id).execute()

    print(response)
```

> {
>
> jola: "sadsa",
>
> saas: 123
>
> }

Comment: Then how is google drive able to show us the contents of a file when we click on it? My motive is just to read a json file contents without downloading it.

Comment: Your browser (client side) is actually making a request to Google (server side) every time that you want to consult a file to actually download the data necessary. If the file is big enough probably you will not be able to see. The thing is that is not actually making a file in your hard drive but more probably storing the data into memory for you to see.
As said you don't need to make an actual file but you won't be able to use `open` neither context manager (`with` statement). 
You can download into a stream (shown above) and read it from there.

Comment: in the above program why is the data being stored in Bytes? can't I use the the io.StringIo() method? 
And while executing your program I got the following error. "The user has not granted the app 692085646907 read access to the file 1bpfdYI8Fo1fofitWFVD9cm9yLUy7DUAr."

Comment: Do you mind explaining the program? By looking at it I am not able to figure out which variable stores the data?

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood your problem. In this case being JSON you can just download them into a string object, executing the request. Also I added some explanation in the first code. This should work for you.

Comment: There is some issue with the permissions. The error says " The user has not granted the app 692085646907 read access to the file 1bpfdYI8Fo1fofitWFVD9cm9yLUy7DUAr. "

Comment: Have you enabled Drive API in your google project? What scope are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have the credentials.json and the token.pickle in my folder . 
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

Comment: You cannot get the file data with this scope. Take a looks at the [scopes aviable](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth). Maybe use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

Comment: Perfect! @LalaLand. Remember to [vote the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that worked for you.

Comment: While reading the contents of .json file using your method, the response variable  which is returned using get_media() is of type ' class <bytes> '. Because this is of type bytes I am not able to edit it, it's immutable. As you know .json file are int the format of List of Dictionaries,  I also need to access some values from response

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? You will need to parse it using the `JSON` module but for me the return is actually a `str`. If you still have problems maybe try to open a new question to get help there.